# How to restrict UIalertview in this code?

Tags: ios, uialertview

I have created a US-format mobile number. This code does not display letters and special characters. It successfully displays but it displays `UIAlertviews`, when the user enters letters and special characters in `UITextfield`, it shows some `UIAlertview`. How can I control the `UIAlertviews`? I want to display only one `Alertview`.

This is the code that I already have:

```
if(textField==mobileNo)
    {
        NSCharacterSet *myCharSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789"];

        for (int i = 0; i < [string length]; i--) {
            unichar c = [string characterAtIndex:i];
            if (![myCharSet characterIsMember:c]) {
                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Alphbets and Special characters not allowed" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
                [alert show];
                return NO;
            }                
        }       
    }
```

Comment: What method is this code in? When is it called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the following... but its not a great solution.....

In your header declare a BOOL to check if the alert view has been shown already, like so:

```
BOOL alertCheck;
```

In your viewDidLoad set it to NO:

```
alertCheck = NO;
```

Then in your code, check it before deciding to display your alertview.

```
if(textField==mobileNo) { 

    NSCharacterSet *myCharSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789"];

    for (int i = 0; i < [string length]; i--) {
        unichar c = [string characterAtIndex:i];
        if (![myCharSet characterIsMember:c]) {
            if (alertCheck == NO) {
                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Alphbets and Special characters not allowed" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
                [alert show];

                alertCheck = YES;
            }
            return NO;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: where to declare BOOL alertcheck;

Comment: @phanindramandarapu As I said in my answer, in your header (.h) code file.

Comment: @Dan Why making a 12 lines code just to check if a string is a number? This is not helping anyone. This code isn't good.

Comment: @FabKremer Calm down. I never said my solution was any good. In fact the first line of my answer says that this is not a good solution. But it does work and just as easy to implement. Its up to the person asking to decide which solution they want to use.

Comment: @Dan I'm so calmed down. I'm just saying you can try to think good solutions before posting quickly to have a couple of points on your reputation :)

Comment: I have created US Mobile format in UITextfield,it allows US Format mobile number successfully(1-222-304-9876), but it also allow this type of numbers (1-234-56). how to restrict numbers, my UITextfield allows only 14 characters. please check my code. how to controll that one.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
if (![myCharSet characterIsMember:c]) {
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        //show the UIAlertView
    });
}
```

Comment: Isn't this a bit overkill for such a trivial problem? Surely using a simple BOOL and just checking it is more appropriate in this case?

Comment: maybe a static variable can be used instead of token but i like this approach more than declaring a property since this is easier to read and keep its track. i personally do not think that it is an overkill because it does not add much complexity to code

Answer (score 0):

That code isn't so nice. You're just checking if the string value is a number or not. To do that you can use [[NSScanner scannerWithString:]](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSScanner_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSScanner/scannerWithString:) this way:

```
 bool isNumber = [[NSScanner scannerWithString: string] scanInt:nil]
 if (!isNumber) {
     UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Alphbets and Special characters not allowed" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
     [alert show];
  }
```

Code seems to be clearer and a lot more simpler.

Hope it helped!